# How to sned and receive chat messages programmatically?

Tags: automation, chat

When I get a chat message from someone on FB or Gmail, how do I go about creating a program that detects the message and then executes some commands accordingly, all programmatically?

Solutions in C++, Java or Python would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion

- Use java & jabber (also called xmpp) protocol
- Install the smack library (jabber library for java, really good!)
- Read about the jabber protocol, in your case pay special attention to the "<presence>" message. The "<presence>" messages will tell you whenever someone connects/disconect/change status on a jabber server.
- Code

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an API for [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/) in a language of your choice. [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php/) uses Jabber ([XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)) which, again, has APIs in many languages.

You are unlikely to simply receive a solution here, this site works more on a basis of helping you with some code that you've already written.